# Help with controller test class. First Attempt!

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

It's my first take on writing Test Class.

> Following is my Apex Class...

```
public class OrderTrackingList{
public OrderTrackingList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}
public list<wrapgroupwise> singlegroup;
public List<wrapgroupwise> getStartHere(){
singlegroup= new List<wrapgroupwise>();
List<orders__c> tempacc=[SELECT Id,Name FROM orders__c where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

 for(Integer i=0; i<tempacc.size() ; i++){
    List <order_lines__c> tempOrderLines=[SELECT Id,name From order_lines__c Where order_number__c=:tempacc[i].id];
    List <shipment_lines__c> tempShipmentLines=[SELECT Id,Name From shipment_lines__c Where Order_Number__c=:tempacc[i].id];

  if(tempOrderLines.size()==0 && tempShipmentLines.size()==0){
          singlegroup.add(new wrapgroupwise(tempacc[i],null,null)); 
    }
    else{

     if(tempShipmentLines.size()==0)
     {
          if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Open')
           {
               tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempOrderLines[i].planned_ship_date__c;
           }

        singlegroup.add(new wrapgroupwise(tempacc[i],tempOrderLines,null)); 

      }   
     else
     {

       if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Open')
       {
           tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempOrderLines[i].planned_ship_date__c;
       }
       if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Invoiced')
       {
           tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempShipmentLines[i].estimated_delivery_date__c;
       }
       if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Shipped but not billed')
       {
           tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempShipmentLines[i].estimated_delivery_date__c;
       }           

      singlegroup.add( new wrapgroupwise(tempacc[i],tempOrderLines,tempShipmentLines)); 
     }

    }
   }
  return singlegroup; 
  }
 public class wrapgroupwise
 {
    public List<order_lines__c> con {get;set;}
    public orders__c acc {get;set;}
    public List<shipment_lines__c> opp {get;set;}

     public wrapgroupwise( orders__c a , list<order_lines__c> c,list<shipment_lines__c> o)
     {
        acc=a;
        con=c;
        opp=o;
      } 
  } 
 }
```

> ========================TEST CLASS===========================

```
 @isTest
 public class GE_PW_OrderTrackingList_Test{ 
static testMethod void coverCode(){

          //GE_PW_OrderTrackingList.wrapgroupwise wgw = new            GE_PW_OrderTrackingList.wrapgroupwise();
          Profile pf= [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE name= 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];

          Account acc = new Account(Name='ABC Corp.');
          insert acc;
          System.assertEquals('ABC Corp.', acc.name);

          gew_orders__c tempOrder = new gew_orders__c();
          tempOrder.name = '0001234567';
          tempOrder.gew_account__c = acc.id;
          insert tempOrder;
          System.assertEquals('0001234567', tempOrder.name);


          gew_order_lines__c tempOL = new gew_order_lines__c();
          tempOL.Name = '10';
          tempOL.gew_number_of_order_lines__c = tempOrder.id;
          insert tempOL;
          System.assertEquals('10', tempOL.name);

          gew_shipment_lines__c tempSL = new gew_shipment_lines__c();
          tempSL.Name = '10'; 
          tempSL.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'; 
          insert tempSL;

          System.assertEquals('USD', tempSL.CurrencyIsoCode);

         GE_PW_OrderTrackingList gepwO = new GE_PW_OrderTrackingList(new ApexPages.StandardController(tempOrder));  
         GE_PW_OrderTrackingList gepwOL = new GE_PW_OrderTrackingList(new ApexPages.StandardController(tempOL));
         GE_PW_OrderTrackingList gepwSL = new GE_PW_OrderTrackingList(new ApexPages.StandardController(tempSL));
         gepwO.getStartHere();
         //gepwOL.singlegroup.add(gepwOL);
        // gepwSL.singlegroup.add(gepwSL);
        // gepwO.singlegroup.add(gepwO);
        }
   }
```

I get 0 Coverage. Why am I getting no test data coverage? What should I be testing? Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at any documentation and guides on how to write test classes ? Please specify why you're having trouble understanding or testing a part of your code.  Asking for your entire class is almost asking us to do the work for you.  This is a good starting point: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Answer (score 3):

After you get all your records inserted you need to:

1. Instantiate your OrderTrackingList class (**I do not see where you are doing this**)
2. Use code to set values and return results asserting they are as expected
3. Repat #2 to work through the methods in the class and ensure everything is working as expected

Also, try reading up on test methods. It is not enough to simply cover lines, you need to ensure that the results obtained both by entering data, and possible negative situations are as expected

Comment: Hi @Eric Thanks for replying. How do I set values? Isn't inserting similar to setting values? A sample code would be helpful. BTW initiating my class resulted in 6% coverage :)

Comment: Updated my test class!